# Menuitem - CSS active state not working

Tags: html, css

I'm struggling to make the active menu element working correctly.
The problem is that menu elements look correctly when hovered, but when selected, the active element doesn't look like hovered element. Th
I'd be thankful for any help.

```css
#menuItems {
  width: 980px;
  height: 36px;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 18px;
  right: 20px;
  top: 150px;
  left: 310px;
  font-size: 23px;
  font-family: Enriqueta-Bold;
  font-weight: bold;
  align-content: center;
  text-align: center;
  background-color: #86ADED;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 6px 6px 0px rgba(34, 50, 60, 0.89);
  -moz-box-shadow: 0px 6px 6px 0px rgba(34, 50, 60, 0.89);
  box-shadow: 0px 6px 6px 0px rgba(34, 50, 60, 0.89);
}
#menuItems ul {
  margin: 0 auto;
  align-items: center;
  text-align: center;
  position: relative;
  right: 2%;
}
#menuItems li {
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 4px 15px;
  align-content: center;
  text-align: center;
}
#menuItems li a {
  text-decoration: none;
  display: block;
  color: black;
}
#menuItems li:hover {
  height: 25px;
  background-Color: #0099FF;
  padding: 12px 15px 15px 15px;
  margin-top: -20px;
  cursor: pointer;
}
#menuItems li.active {
  height: 25px;
  background-Color: #0099FF;
  padding: 12px 15px 15px 15px;
  margin-top: -20px;
  cursor: pointer;
}
#menuItems li:hover a {
  color: white;
  padding-bottom: -20px;
}
#menuItems li.active a {
  color: white;
  padding-bottom: -20px;
}
```

```html
<div id="menuItems">
  <ul>
    <li>@Html.ActionLink("About", "About", "Home")</li>
    <li>@Html.ActionLink("Interests", "Interests", "Home")</li>
    <li>@Html.ActionLink("Price List", "PriceList", "Home")</li>
    <li>@Html.ActionLink("Contact", "Contact", "Home")</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use colons instead of a period.  :active, not .active

Also - the active state style is the same as the hover state style.

Comment: Ok, thanks. 
However, what I want to achieve is to have the selected/currently opened menu item of the same style as hovered element. I'm wondering whether it can be achieved using css or I need to use jquery.

Comment: You can add another css class like ".selected_menuitem" for example, which has the same style as the :hover.